# If, for every $n$, $f_n\to0$ at infinity and $|f_n(x_n)|\geq C$, can one deduce that $(x_n)$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\|f_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)} \geq C >0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ (where $C>0$ is fixed constant)

Therefore, we have

(1) There exists $\{x_n\}\subset \mathbb R$ such that  $$|f_n(x_n)| \geq C $$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Assume that $|f_n(x)| \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty.$

> Question: Can we say $\{x_n\}$  (as obtained in (1) above) is bounded? In other words, Dose there exists $M>0$ such that $|x_n|\leq M$ for all $n$, and $|f_n(x_n)| \geq C$?

Comment: No we cannot. The basic example is when $f_n(x)=h(x/n)$ with $h(x)\to0$ when $|x|\to\infty$, then $f_n(n)=h(1)$ hence there is no reason to expect that $f_n(n)\to0$ although $x_n=n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did: I have assume that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $n$ as $|x|\to \infty.$ If I understood correctly, your example does not match with this? Correct me If I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes it does, please read more carefully my comment.

Comment: @Did: Thanks.  One more thing.  We assume that  $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty} \geq  C$, So there EXISTS  $\{x_n\}$ with $|f_n(x_n)|\geq C$. But at priori how we can assume that  $x_n=n$?  Can you say a bit more on this?

Comment: Of course, a priori one **cannot** assume that $x_n=n$. *In the example explained in my first comment*, the choice $x_n=n$ leads to a contradiction. By the way, in some cases, the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded, only there is no general result asserting that $(x_n)$ must be bounded, as the counterexample in my comment shows. (Phew, you seem really lost, sorry to say...)

Comment: @Did: Sorry for the mess-up. And thanks, again.

Answer (score -1):

This is false in general.

This can happen: Take something like a piecewise affine function on $\mathbb R$ which is $0$ outside $(0,1/n)$, such that $f(1/2n) = C$ and extends linearly on $(0,1/n)$. This is continuous and there is pointwise convergence to $0$ everywhere. The sequence $1/2n$ is bounded.

Now, notice that the same construction with the interval being $(n,n+1)$ gives you a counter-example.